# Running Symfony app/console I got error about Zend lib

Tags: symfony, zend-framework, composer-php

I had to run something on the command line in Symfony 2 that uses Zend lib and I got the following error

```
Fatal error: Class 'Zend\XmlRpc\Client' not found in
```

I try to run it on production environment.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with auto loading. Also composer install failed. Running composer

```
composer install -o
```

solved the problem. It fix the issue with autoloading of Zend lib.

Comment: @TomášVotruba I can accept it as the best solution only after 2 days.

Comment: Ah, didn't know that. Thanks for info